# Jackson - @JsonCreator return generics

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson2, jackson-databind, vavr

I want to integrate vavr validation library in my command dto's in a way that when command dto is deserialized from  request, return type of the static factory will be Try but jackson is throwing following error :

> Type definition error: [simple type, class com.foo.command.FooCommand]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.foo.command.FooCommand` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Here is FooCommand

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class FooCommand {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    @JsonCreator
    public static Try<FooCommand> of(
            @JsonProperty("foo") String foo,
            @JsonProperty("bar") String bar
    ) {
        return Try.of(() -> {
            //Validate values
        });
    }
}
```

I am using spring 5 and it's annotated to deserialize request body automatically into controller parameter. 
Is something like this possible ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does FooCommand looks like? The class in your question is `RegisterConfiguration` but the return value is `Try<FooCommand>`.

Comment: I have corrected class name in example to FooCommand. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you should create a constructor and put `@JsonCreator` on top of the constructor

Comment: How is then FooCommand::of() method going to be called?

Comment: @SilvioMarijic
`I am using spring 5 and it's annotated to deserialize request body automatically`
I guess Spring calls it.

Comment: It seems like Jackson only uses factory methods if they have the same return type even if they got the `@JsonCreator` Annotation.

Comment: Yeah, that is wierd, I have no clue why that restriction on the return type. Everything works fine when I just return instance of FooCommand without wrapping it in a Try

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I fixed by using Converters: [Using Jackson, how can I deserialize values using static factory methods that return wrappers with a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75052490/426371)

I haven't yet found how to apply the converters automatically, so you have to annotate every occurrence of the wrapped type in your requests.

```java
public class Request {
    @JsonDeserialize(converter = FooCommandConverter.class)
    Try<FooCommand> command;
}
```

You can write a [Converter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) like so:

```java
public class FooCommandConverter
        extends StdConverter<FooCommandConverter.DTO, Try<FooCommand>> {

    @Override
    public Try<FooCommand> convert(FooCommandConverter.DTO dto) {
        return FooCommand.of(
            dto.foo,
            dto.bar
        );
    }

    public static class DTO {
        public String foo;
        public String bar;
    }
}
```